# capture multiple values from grid view to pass to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, parameter-passing

asp.net and C#

here I have the columns from a gridview control

when the user clicks either button i need to pass the values for CaseID, CaseworkerID, EventDate and Code to a stored procedure

but how do i pass multiple parameters to my onclick method ????

```
<columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="CaseID" HeaderText="CaseID" Visible = "False" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="caseworkerID" HeaderText="CwID" Visible = "False" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="CaseWorker" HeaderText="Case Worker" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="EventDate" HeaderText="Event Date" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Code" HeaderText="Code" />
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ADD">
       <ItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:Button  ID="AddUnit" runat="server" Text=" +1 " onserverclick="AddUnit_Click"/>
        </ItemTemplate> 
   </asp:TemplateField> 

<asp:BoundField DataField="TotalUnits" HeaderText="Total Units" />

  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DDT">
       <ItemTemplate> 
          <asp:Button ID="DdtUnit" runat="server" Text=" -1 " onserverclick="DdtUnit_Click"/>
        </ItemTemplate> 
   </asp:TemplateField> 


<asp:BoundField DataField="EventType" HeaderText="Event Type" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="UnitCost" HeaderText="Unit Cost" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="TotalCost" HeaderText="Total Cost"/>
```

EDIT:
so I now have this

```
            <ItemTemplate> 
                <asp:Button  ID="AddUnit" runat="server" Text=" +1 " 
                CommandName="AddUnit" 
                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CaseID")+ ";" + Eval("caseworkerID")+ ";" + Eval("EventDate")+ ";" + Eval("Code")%>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
```

thats a good start

Comment: Hi! You should look into the `commandargument` and `commandname` attributes of the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much what you want to do is create a commandargument thats deliminated by a special character(s). When you handle the event, pull out the command argument from the event (e) and split it. (As utkarshs answer shows, use the gridviews rowcommand event, not an onclick)

This can cause issues if the commandargument data actually contains the same character you used for a deliminator. Just one suggestion though (we do this sometimes when we know someting like a productId won't contain a pipe (|) )

EDIT:
So your button should be something like...

```
  <asp:button CommandArgument='<%# Eval("someValue") + " | " 
              + Eval("someOtherValue") + " | " %>'  
             CommandName="whatever" runat="server" text="FOO BAR" />
```

Then in your code behind where your grid id is `gridId`

```
protected void gridId_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "btnname")
    {
        string[] differentValues = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split("|");           
    }
}
```

Comment: okay so we have an event handler thing not on an on click event,,

Comment: @Sonny123 Yup, since each row will have its own button in the gridview you want to handle the gridview "RowCommand" handler, like Utkarsh does. However, Use e.CommandArgument and split it on a deliminator. Then you can pass as many values through the button click as you want. You just have to build them up dynamically. See edit

Comment: im still with it,, But  compiler says CommandArgument is an object (not a String) so there is no method to split..  but i get the idea of making an array.  also if Eval("someValue") gets a string value, will Eval(someValue) get an integer or is it better to pass all as string and cast it later in the code behind?

Comment: @Sony123 yup thats it, Sorry was going off of memory. Just opened up VS to work with it. Cast it later in the code behind, because you'll still have to .ToString() the CommandArgument and cast it back anyway

Comment: e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(new char[] { ';' });   Ill get the syntax eventually!!   and Now im a happy bunny!  thanks for your help

Comment: @Sonny123 no problem! If this answer was the correct one please click on the white check mark to the left of my answer (it will turn green)  :)

Answer (score 2):

first of use different commandname for all button of grid

```
protected void grid_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string city="";
    if (e.CommandName == "btnname")
    {
        ImageButton imgbtn = (ImageButton)e.CommandSource;
        GridViewRow rows = (GridViewRow)imgbtn.NamingContainer;
        city = grid.Rows[rows.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text;           
    }

}
```

use as per your requirement use cell id of column. and column id start from 0.

any query ask me

Comment: Yeah, I was just saying I couldn't remember the name of when I wrote my answer, brain fart ;)