# Link Button in asp.net click event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkbutton

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbDownloadFile" name = "lbDownloadFile" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" 
                            onclick="lbDownloadFile_Click" />
```

I have this link button. on click:

```
protected void lbDownloadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    //here is my debug pointer/breakpoint
    .........................
}
```

but this event is not firing. my Page_Load() event is firing. How to solve this problem?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Session[Antrage_AnfrageSessionNames.AgntNr] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("../UserSessionError.aspx");
        }

        try
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["Kundennummer"].ToString() != null)
            {
                //If kundennummer exists in QueryString then stores it to further use 
                kundennummer = Request.QueryString["Kundennummer"].ToString();                    
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            kundennummer = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I am adding the code, what FireFox firebug shows me respective to the LinkButton.
[image]

I think the auto generated **href** is the main problem here.

Comment: are you sure putting same name of event for client and server would work?

Comment: no. I didn't put it first. onClientClick was writen there later to try, if it works.

Comment: well i suspect it is OnClick not onclick, case sensitive issue might be

Comment: `portected` spelling mistake. It should be `protected`

Comment: but it would throw syntax error not will even compile

Comment: "...instead of this event, my Page_Load() event is firing..." - This is part of the normal ASP .NET WebForms Page Lifecycle... Page Load is called **EVERY** time a postback occurs. After PageLoad your event should then fire... **BUT** Are you doing anything in Page Load that would stop this from happening?

Comment: Yes, I understand the page load. Thanks. I am just getting a value from query string in page_load while it's !IsPostBack

Comment: Can i see your page-load event codes?

Comment: Would you happen to be creating this LinkButton in a GridView, or a similar structure? Event handlers for controls in these structures don't work the way you think they do...

Comment: @Steve `OnClick` event should fire irrespective of place where the control is placed right?

Comment: @Bharadwaj No, when you place these in structures like that you have to use CommandArgument, see the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896125/capture-multiple-values-from-grid-view-to-pass-to-a-stored-procedure/14896507#14896507

Comment: @Steve Its not like "You have to", but like "You can also". `OnClick` will also work for `Buttons` inside `Listing` controls.

Comment: @Steve I am using `OnClick` in all my `GridView`, `DataGridView` and its working :) Besides, `CommandArgument` is just to hold values, `CommandName` will hold what the button is meant for.

Comment: @Bharadwaj MSDN begs to differ...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx

Comment: @Steve that says `Buttons within a GridView control can also invoke some of the built-in functionality of the control.` So its not like "You have to".

Comment: Hey Guy's Please see my answer, It's may be helps to him! :)

Comment: page load event is added. you just ask if u want to know

Comment: Try removing `OnClientClick="lbDownloadFile_Click"`

Comment: `OnClientClick="lbDownloadFile_Click"` is not the fact. I have tried removing this

Comment: Then try deleting `Designer.cs` file and regenerate it.

Comment: `Please check the link button was OUTSIDE of my form elements`

Comment: @Bharadwaj After further research it turns out I could be mistaken. Good call.

Comment: @AbdurRahim Please see now **Edit 2** in my answer

Answer (score 4):

@belogix comment is Good

> This is part of the normal ASP .NET WebForms Page Lifecycle... Page Load is called EVERY time a postback occurs. After PageLoad your event should then fire... BUT Are you doing anything in Page Load that would stop this from happening?

**I think Your Page load method have did anything wrong. May be your link button was reload from page load event.**

**Sample Error**

If you using grid view and also this link button in inside of your grid, You are doing this things

- Write Grid bind method
- then you called the grid bind method in page load event

Your code look like now

```
Page_load()
{
// called here Grid bind method
}
```

Now, the grid reload on every post back .

**Solution**

Now you must need to set `!IsPostBack`  and then call the grid bind method in inside of `!IsPostBack`

The code look like

```
Page_load()
{
if(!IsPostBack)
{
// called here Grid bind method

}
}
```

This is your problem. **and Also it's my guess.**

> Please tell me if you not use any controls(Gridview,listview,etc)

---

**Edit**

Your code is working to me if i don't write any code on page-load event

See

**Default.aspx**

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDownloadFile" Text="he he he" name="lbDownloadFile" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="lbDownloadFile_Click"
        OnClick="lbDownloadFile_Click" />
```

and server side code is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // Empty code 
    }

    protected void lbDownloadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

this is fine for me, So you missed anything in page load event

*`OnClientClick` and `onclick` have not any problems. The problems created on pageload event,

Please post your `pageload` code, otherwise we can't solve it. :)

## Edit 2

- **Please check the link button was OUTSIDE of your form elements. This link button should be inside of the form element**
- And your page load event should be

`protected void Page_Load(**object sender, EventArgs e**)
        {
     //Code
        }`

Not

```
protected void Page_Load(){}
```

You have missed

```
object sender, EventArgs e
```

Comment: Page_Load event is added. Please check if u can help.

Comment: @AbdurRahim Please check the link button was OUTSIDE of my form elements

Comment: @AbdurRahim Please now see my Edit 2

Comment: i have mistaken to write. they are there. I am looking at your first point. trying to regenerate the aspx.designer.cs file.

Comment: yes. It executes fine. to the end brace. then direcly comes to the aspx page, where several data is bound.

Comment: I am trying to see my designer.cs file. i have found a way `Convert to Web Application`. But will it harm my normal web site?

Comment: @AbdurRahim did you check `The link button was OUTSIDE of your form elements`? This link button should be inside of the form element

Comment: @AbdurRahim , OOPs I can't get you, What you mean `Convert to Web Application`? Is is not Web Application?

Comment: `Control is inside form element. `    No, Its an web site.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52108/discussion-between-user256103-and-abdur-rahim)

Answer (score 1):

I have created demo project and copy same code as you have written.It is working fine

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDownloadFile" name = "lbDownloadFile" Text="Click me" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="lbDownloadFile_Click"
                            onclick="lbDownloadFile_Click" />
```

in code behind file

```
  protected void lbDownloadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    //here is my debug pointer/breakpoint
        }
```

I have just added text on link button.

Comment: I think the OP have dynamically added the `Text` . This is not a problem, This problem coming from page-load event. But OP did't put that code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just go to button properties and set

```
UseSubmitBehaviour= False
```