# Linkbutton click event not firing in master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, linkbutton

I have the following in my master page:

```
 <div class="navigation">
  <ul class="main-menu">
<li class="about"><asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnSubmitLeaveRequest" runat="server" OnClick="lbtnSubmitLeaveRequest_Click" CausesValidation="false">Submit Leave Request</asp:LinkButton></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

And in the code-behind:

```
  protected void lbtnSubmitLeaveRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbtnLeaveHidden_ModalPopupExtender.Show();
        }
```

But the click event is not firing.

EDIT: If I use a normal Button it works, but the linkbutton is not working.

Comment: Does it post-back?  (i.e. Can you breakpoint in the page init / load)

Comment: @freefaller. NO its not doing a post-back

Comment: Then there's your problem - check your browsers developer tools

Comment: Place a breakpoint @ lbtnLeaveHidden_ModalPopupExtender.Show(); line and check once again.

Comment: try this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493962/link-button-in-asp-net-click-event-not-firing
I hope it will helpful